# use blockon in rust wasm

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

i want to use block_on in rust when compiling to wasm.
The problem is i am using egui and want to compile it to web. Its function are sync and i need to block async functions. I tried with async_futures, but it seems to start the future, but not blocking it.

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn test1() {
    alert("Hello, 1");

    async_std::task::block_on(async {
        alert("Hello, 2");
        async_std::task::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
        alert("Hello, 3");
    });

    alert("Hello, 4");
}
```

The output would be in order `1, 4, 2, 3`.

It does not emit any binding which i could use to check if its done and i cant pass in a mutex since i would need to await it outside of the async code which is not possible. Any idea how to block it?

I was expecting the output `1, 2, 3, 4`

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible [to run blocking code](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2111) in a webbrowser.

Browser vendors do not allow this. It is basically the same as in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449207/4593433).

If this would be possible, it would be a way to run asynchronous code in a synchronous JavaScript function (since `test1` will be invoked from JavaScript) which [is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121902/call-an-asynchronous-javascript-function-synchronously).

This is also an [open issue](https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/issues/913) in [`async-std`](https://crates.io/crates/async-std) (note that the mention of [`pollster`](https://crates.io/crates/pollster) seems to be incorrect, as it panicked on the `.await`ed statement when I tried to use `pollster::block_on`).

Answer (score 0):

You may use crate [pollster](https://github.com/zesterer/pollster)

```rust
use pollster::FutureExt as _;

let my_fut = async {};

let result = my_fut.block_on();
```